# How do i find the click event on indicator in radar chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, echarts

My project uses echart to create radar chart and i have to find click event for indicators around radar chart.
It is implemented like this.

```
createradarchart() {
  this.theme.getJsTheme()
    .pipe(
      takeWhile(() => this.alive),
      delay(1),
    )
    .subscribe(config => {
        this.options = {
          name: 'KPI Radar',
          grid: {
                left: '5%',
                right: '5%',
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0
          },
          // label: {
          //   distance: 5
          // },
          type: 'radar',
          color: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
          legend: {
                  bottom: 5,
                  itemGap: 20,
                  data: ['Baseline', 'Threshold', 'Actual'],
                  textStyle: {
                      color: 'black',
                      fontSize: 10
                  }
          },
          radar: {
            indicator: this.indicator,
            nameGap: 5,
            shape: 'circle',
            radius: '43%',
            name: {
              textStyle: {
                  color: 'black',
                  fontSize: 10
              }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          show: true,
          textStyle: {fontSize:10},
          trigger: 'item',
          formatter: (params => {
             return params['name']+'-'+params['value'][1];
        })
        },
        series: this.seriesdata,
      };

       this.ctx = this.echartsIntance.getRenderedCanvas();
       this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx,{type:'radar', options: this.options})
        // this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    });
}
```

where data and options are in format, with data being fetched from server:

```
seriesdata: any = {type: 'radar', data:[{name:'Baseline',value:[1,2,3,4,5]},{name:'Threshold',value:[1,2,3,4,5]},{name:'Actual',value:[1,2,3,4,5]}]};
  indicator = [
    { name: 'DL User Thpt_Kbps[CDBH]', max: 100 },
    { name: 'ERAB SSR[CDBH]', max: 100 },
    { name: 'PS DCR %[CDBH]', max: 100 },
    { name: 'VoLTE CSSR', max: 100 },
    { name: 'VoLTE DCR[CBBH]', max: 100 }
  ];
  options: EChartOption = {
          name: 'KPI Radar',
          grid: {
            left: '2%',
            right: '2%',
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
          },
          // label:{
          //   distance: 5
          // },
          type: 'radar',
          color: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
          legend: {
                  orient: 'vertical',
                  align: 'left',
                  right: 20,
                  data: ['Baseline', 'Threshold', 'Actual'],
                  textStyle: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontSize: 10
                }
          },
          radar: {
            indicator: this.indicator,
            nameGap: 5,
            shape: 'circle',
            radius:'60%',

        },
        tooltip: {
          show: false,
        //   trigger: 'item',
        //   formatter: (params => {
        //     return params['name']+'-'+params['value'][1];
        // })
      }
  };
```

This is where i want click event to be triggered, having the name of label which is clicked.

Approach i found to do this is this, but it didnt work, i debugged and found that scale.pointLabels is empty.

```
labelClicked(e:any){
  var self = this;
  var helpers = Chart.helpers;
  var scale = self.chart.scale;
  var opts = scale.options;
  var tickOpts = opts.ticks;

  // Position of click relative to canvas.
  var mouseX = e.offsetX;
  var mouseY = e.offsetY;

  var labelPadding = 5; // number pixels to expand label bounding box by

  // get the label render position
  // calcs taken from drawPointLabels() in scale.radialLinear.js
  var tickBackdropHeight = (tickOpts.display && opts.display) ?
      helpers.valueOrDefault(tickOpts.fontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize)
      + 5: 0;
  var outerDistance = scale.getDistanceFromCenterForValue(opts.ticks.reverse ? scale.min : scale.max);
  for (var i = 0; i < scale.pointLabels.length; i++) {
      // Extra spacing for top value due to axis labels
      var extra = (i === 0 ? tickBackdropHeight / 2 : 0);
      var pointLabelPosition = scale.getPointPosition(i, outerDistance + extra + 5);

      // get label size info.
      // TODO fix width=0 calc in Brave?
      // https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/1738
      var plSize = scale._pointLabelSizes[i];

      // get label textAlign info
      var angleRadians = scale.getIndexAngle(i);
      var angle = helpers.toDegrees(angleRadians);
      var textAlign = 'right';
      if (angle == 0 || angle == 180) {
          textAlign = 'center';
      } else if (angle < 180) {
          textAlign = 'left';
      }

      // get label vertical offset info
      // also from drawPointLabels() calcs
      var verticalTextOffset = 0;
      if (angle === 90 || angle === 270) {
          verticalTextOffset = plSize.h / 2;
      } else if (angle > 270 || angle < 90) {
          verticalTextOffset = plSize.h;
      }

      // Calculate bounding box based on textAlign
      var labelTop = pointLabelPosition.y - verticalTextOffset - labelPadding;
      var labelHeight = 2*labelPadding + plSize.h;
      var labelBottom = labelTop + labelHeight;

      var labelWidth = plSize.w + 2*labelPadding;
      var labelLeft;
      switch (textAlign) {
      case 'center':
         labelLeft = pointLabelPosition.x - labelWidth/2;
        break;
      case 'left':
         labelLeft = pointLabelPosition.x - labelPadding;

        break;
      case 'right':
         labelLeft = pointLabelPosition.x - labelWidth + labelPadding;
        break;
      default:
        console.log('ERROR: unknown textAlign '+textAlign);
      }
      var labelRight = labelLeft + labelWidth;

      // Render a rectangle for testing purposes
      self.ctx.save();
      self.ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
      self.ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      self.ctx.strokeRect(labelLeft, labelTop, labelWidth, labelHeight);
      self.ctx.restore();

      // compare to the current click
      if (mouseX >= labelLeft && mouseX <= labelRight && mouseY <= labelBottom && mouseY >= labelTop) {
          alert(scale.pointLabels[i]+' clicked');
          // Break loop to prevent multiple clicks, if they overlap we take the first one.
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using [Echarts](https://www.echartsjs.com/) or [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/)? You've tagged both and your code seems to mix both.

Comment: Project was using echarts, but i couldnt find way in it to detect events on label, so i stupidly created instance of "echart canvas" with chartjs constructor, but i saw my mistake, and had to convert code to chartjs for event to work, it is working now, Thank you for your time and effort.